# Angular, TinyMCE 5 GET http://localhost:4200/tinymce/themes/silver/theme.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found) error

Tags: angular, configuration, tinymce, tinymce-5

I am integrating TinyMCE into my Angular 13 project and it was working fine until this error started popping up   :

Here is a picture of the error in console.
[image]

[image]
I am new to Angular but from what I understand, Angular cannot find the files for the theme.

Here is the relevant part of the angular.json file

```
   "assets": [ 
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ]
            ,
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"
            ]
```

here is the initialization for the editor

```
 init={
    base_url: '/tinymce', // Root for resources
    suffix: '.min' ,       // Suffix to use when loading resources
    height: 300,
     plugins: [
       'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor',
       'searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen',
       'insertdatetime media table paste code help wordcount'
     ],
    menubar: false,
    toolbar: 'undo redo | formatselect | fontselect | fontsizeselect |'+
    '| bold italic backcolor | alignleft aligncenter ' +
    'alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent |' +
    'removeformat | link image media |',
    font_formats: 'Arial=arial,helvetica,sans-serif; Courier New=courier new,courier,monospace',
    
  };
```

version of tinymce

```
 "@tinymce/tinymce-angular": "^4.2.4",
    "rxjs": "~7.4.0",
    "tinymce": "^5.10.2",
```

I have tried to fix this the last 2 hours using various blogs and cannot find the issue. If anyone can point out the issue or help in any kind of way..

Comment: Did you got the solution for this?

Comment: Nope. one time i compiled, and the issue just went away. i'm very stumped